# Angular routing default location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

any idea why the app redirects to 'dashboards/projects'??

I want to allow parameters on my angular app e.g

```
http://localhost/rxjob/#!/app/project_detail?id=1
```

route script:  `https://adrivanrex.github.io/rxjob/js/config.js`

controller: `https://adrivanrex.github.io/rxjob/js/controller.js`

Live site: https://adrivanrex.github.io/rxjob/

Comment: Link to repo-files is good and all, but you should always include code here so that If your repo changes then your question does not become useless to everyone else. Edit the question, include the code you think is relevant. Add more if someone asks.

Comment: You do have ` $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard_1");` but nowhere do you have a state with that url. (Which is likely the source of your problem.)

Comment: @ippi I already input a state for the /dashboards/dashboard_1

Comment: I don't know how it redirects to dashbords/projects

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Where does it redirect to dashboards/projects? Are you talking about your oauth implementations? (don't expect us to test that for you, sorry) anyway, then it's probably related to your settings in google dev console. If you do not believe that's the case, then you need to set up a simple reproducible case where we can see or test the problem for ourselves. Or at the very least tell us where the problem is!

Comment: @ippi no bro, It's not about the google auth. but about the routing it goes to 'dashbords/projects' well in fact I did not set that redirect

Comment: I've so far seen no routing to 'dashbords/projects'.

Comment: @ippi yes that's the point.. it's a bug with angular otherwise?

Comment: guess it's not implemented yet

Comment: `MainCtrl`: `if($location.path('/dashboards/projects'))`  `$location.path` called without parameters returns current path, if you call it with a parameter it will change the path. So you are changing paths in your if-calls. I believe ui.router is pretty much feature complete.

Comment: @ippi thanks bro.. I'll check the current path.. I dont really know why the defualt path turned to 'dashbords/projects'...

Comment: By doing this: `if($location.path('/dashboards/projects'))` you are changing path.

Comment: @ippi thanks it solve the problem..